# need to split dataframe columns using comma delimited

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a data frame column-like,

```
comments
misha,park@gmail.com,233432
ammesh,,3545657
",,,"
neta,ne34@gmail.com,,
```

I want to split using comma, when two comma occurs conituosly need to fill that column as NA. When three comma occurs need to fill all the three columns as NA (like in the third row)

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT :
comments                              name          mail             phone
misha,park@gmail.com,233432          misha      park@gmail.com      233432
ammesh,,3545657                      ammesh          NA             3545657
",,,"                                 NA             NA               NA
neta,ne34@gmail.com,,                neta       ne34@gmail.com        NA
```

CODE USED:

```
b = a.join(a['comments'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('comments')).fillna(np.nan)
```

Comment: Is you dataset large? Would it work with simple looping?

Answer (score 0):

In case you will not find something more pythonic, the following code should work properly. I tried to cover all scenarios of ',,' appearance:

```
a['name']=''
a['mail']=''
a['phone']=''

for i in range(len(a)):
    if ',,' not in a.comments.iloc[i] and ',,,' not in a.comments.iloc[i]:
        s=a.comments.iloc[i].split(',')
        a['name'].iloc[i]=s[0]
        a['mail'].iloc[i]=s[1]
        a['phone'].iloc[i]=s[2]
    elif ',,,' in a.comments.iloc[i]:
        a['name'].iloc[i]=np.nan
        a['mail'].iloc[i]=np.nan
        a['phone'].iloc[i]=np.nan   
    else:
        s=a.comments.iloc[i].split(',')
        if len(s)==5:
            a['name'].iloc[i]=np.nan
            a['mail'].iloc[i]=s[2]
            a['phone'].iloc[i]=np.nan 
        if len(s)==4:
            if s[0]=='':
                a['name'].iloc[i]=np.nan
                a['mail'].iloc[i]=s[2]
                a['phone'].iloc[i]=s[3]
            elif s[-1]=='':
                a['name'].iloc[i]=s[0]
                a['mail'].iloc[i]=s[1]
                a['phone'].iloc[i]=np.nan
         if len(s)==3:
             a['name'].iloc[i]=s[0]
             a['mail'].iloc[i]=np.nan
             a['phone'].iloc[i]=s[2]
print(a)
```